# how to filter a model in a listview

Tags: django

I have a page that displays a list of interviewers and some important info about each user.
One of the things that I want it to show is the number of users who have been interviewed by that specific interviewer.
I wrote a view like this:

```
class ManagerUsers(ListView):
model = User
template_name = 'reg/manager-users.html'
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['scientific_interviewers'] = User.objects.filter(role='theory_interviewer').all()

    context['interviewed_number'] = len(ScientificInfo.objects.filter(user__role='applicant', is_approved=True, interviewer=?????))
```

the interviewer field should be equal to that object's user but I don't know what to do exactly.
the output should be something like this:
object 1 : user's name, user's other info, user's interviewed_number
....

these are my models:

```
USER_ROLE_CHOICES = (('0', 'applicant'),
                 ('1', 'theory_interviewer'),)

class User(AbstractUser):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
role = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, choices=USER_ROLE_CHOICES, default=USER_ROLE_CHOICES[0][0])
username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=13)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default=None)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, default=None)

class ScientificInfo(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
interviewer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='interviewer')
is_approved = boolean field
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Comment: check the question again I added the models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [**`.get_queryset()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) to return only the interviewers. By using [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) you can add an extra attribute to these `User`s:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class ManagerUsersView(ListView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'scientific_interviewers'
    template_name = 'reg/manager-users.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_querset().filter(
            role='1'
        ).annotate(
            interviewed_number=Count('interviewer', filter=Q(interviewer__user__role='0', interviewer__is_approved=True))
        )
```

The `User`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.interviewed_number` with the number of approved `ScientificInfo`s where that user was the `interviewer`.

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `ManagerUsersView`, instead of <s>`ManagerUsers`</s>.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `ScientificInfo`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`interviewer`</s> relation to `interviews`.